# Adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI to .Net 6 Blazor Webassembly Shared project causes build Error

Tags: asp.net-identity, identity, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I needed to move my ApplicationUser class to my Shared project for Blazor Webassembly .Net 6 so I could use it in my other Shared objects.  It required a reference to Identity.

When I add a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI to the Shared project, I get the following error:

Error   NETSDK1082  There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.    WaterWithdrawl.Client   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets   427

I did not change anything from the Visual Studio .Net 6 Blazor Assemble Template

[image: SDKs][image]

[image]

Comment: You don't need UI, you only need Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: You shouldn't add anything form *.Identity to the Shared project. Inefficient and unsafe. Use a DTO for the User.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI is not needed to reference Identity in the Shared project, you only need Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore